# CatBoost Post-Training Feature Information

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-engineering, catboost

I would like to understand how I can access information about numerical and categorical features *after* training a CatBoost model. For the sake of example, here's some toy code:

```
import pandas as pd
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool

train_pool = Pool(pd.DataFrame({'size': [1,1,2,1],
                                'shape': ['square','square','square', 'circle']}),
                  [1,1,0,1],
                  feature_names = ['size','shape'],
                  cat_features= ['shape'])

model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=2,
                           cat_features = ['shape'],
                           ctr_leaf_count_limit=1)

model.fit(train_pool, plot=False)
```

I would now like to run a function on the `model` object to obtain the following:

- Numerical Feature `size` has minimum value `0`, and max value `1` (this should be part of CatBoosts split logic for numerical features)
- Categorical Feature `shape` has the following training values:

  `values=['square', None]`.

  Notice that `circle` is *not* in `values` because the `car_leaf_count_limit=1` would have selected the most occurring value, which in this case is `'square'`. I've put `None` here because I'm pretty sure cat boost will assign `None` to any unseen classes.

  Next, I've chosen the above data example to make sure that CatBoost decides to split on `shape=='square'`. Ideally I'd like to see an array `used_values=['square']` which emphasizes that there was at least one split on this `square` value.

It's important to emphasize here that I want to operate on the `model` object only. Obviously, one can get some of these details by running functions onto of the training data. My motivation is to *double-make-sure* that I completely understand the training-range of inputs into the model, and what it may do to them in preprocessing.